# Ionic content scroll is disabled

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

i have made chat application using ionic. Ionic content is scrollable.
I have made a directive **"focus-on-keyboard-open"** in which when user clicks on keyboard, mobile keyboard opens up and the scroll goes down in the ionic-content. and when user click outside the keyboard, the keyboard goes down and scroll down again. the problem is when I close the key board, scroll becomes disable in ionic content and I have to refresh a view to make ionic content scrollable again. 
here is html code

```
<ion-content id="{{conversationId}}" on-scroll="onChatScroll(10)" delegate-handle="chat-convo-handle" class="has-header main-bg lg-chat-bg" ng-click="keyboardhide()">
    ....
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar class="custom-lg-bar lg-br-top sb-bg" keyboard-attach>
    <textarea id="txtbox1" ng-keyup="keyup()" ng-keydown="keydown()" ng-blur="blur()" ng-change="change()" class="lg-text-area sb-bg" rows="1" msd-elastic ng-model="$root.chatFactory.msg_txt" placeholder="Type your message..." data-emojiable="true" focus-on-keyboard-open hidekeyboard="hidekeyboard"></textarea>
    </ion-footer-bar>
```

the directive is used in text area. here is my directive code.

```
.directive('focusOnKeyboardOpen', function($window, $ionicScrollDelegate, $timeout) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            hidekeyboard: '=hidekeyboard'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var keyboardOpen = false;
            // require cordova plugin https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard
            $window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', function(e) {
                keyboardOpen = true;
                element[0].focus();
                $timeout(function() {
                    $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('chat-convo-handle').scrollBottom(true);
                    $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('comment-handle').scrollBottom(true);
                    $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('post-comment-handle').scrollBottom(true);
                }, 0);

            });
            $window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', function(e) {
                keyboardOpen = false;
                // if (scope.hidekeyboard) {
                element[0].blur();
                // }

            });



            element[0].addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
                if (scope.hidekeyboard) {
                    keyboardOpen = false;
                    scope.hidekeyboard = false;
                } else {
                    if (keyboardOpen) {
                        element[0].focus();
                    }
                }


            }, true);
        }
    };
})
```

i am unable to understand why scrolling becomes disabled in ionic content. help anyone. also in my controller and im using click event on ionic content which closes down the keyboard,

```
$scope.hidekeyboard = false;
$scope.keyboardhide = function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('chat-convo-handle').resize();
    $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('chat-convo-handle').scrollBottom(true);
    $scope.hidekeyboard = true;
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();
}
```

here is a screenshot of my ionic content chat application
[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the freeze to false.

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('your-handle').freezeScroll(false);
```

see if that works